# Use VLC from node app started by linux service

Tags: node.js, linux, raspberry-pi, vlc

I have a raspberry with a node server which, via endpoint, should start vlc with RC interface. It works in dev on Windows. It works when, on Raspberry Linux I start Node server with console. As I want the node server to start on Linux startup, I had a service which starts node script. Then, VLC cannot be started anymore, I get error:

```
{"errno":-111,"code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"::1","port":4212}
```

This is the service used on linux

```
[Unit]
Description=Description

[Service]
User=root (I tried different user without any success)
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/screenwise/backend
ExecStart=npm run live-prod (I also tried with absolute path to npm)
StandardOutput=file:/var/www/html/screenwise/backend/node-logs.log
StandardError=file:/var/www/html/screenwise/backend/node-logs.log
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thanks for your help